# Как изменить высоту ImageView с помощью nslayout?

Tags: ios

В сториборде высота `ImageView = 60`. Как мне изменить ее программно до `100`?

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect frame = imageView.frame;
frame.size.height = 100;
imageView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score -1):

Задать констрейнт высоты, и через параметр `imageOutlet.constant` изменять высоту